# Ubuntu Upstart script hangs on start and stop

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, upstart

I have an upstart script that will start a custom jetty server. When I do `sudo start [myservice]` nothing happens. Subsequently, `sudo status [myservice]` show it as: `[myservice] start/killed, process 3586`.

Here's the script in /etc/init/[myservice].conf:

```
description "[description]"
author "[my name and email]"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
expect fork
script
    sudo -u www-data /path/to/grafserv-start.sh >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
end-script
```

And here is `grafserv-start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -Djetty.port=3070 -jar /path/to/grafserv/trunk/start.jar
echo "Done starting GrafServ"
```

I've tried redirecting the output of the script command to a tmp logfile, but that file is never created. When I start it, I just get a hang, until I ^C. Also, I tried running it with strace but that gave me a lot of stuff about sockets.

Comment: Just a sanity check: is there actually code in start.jar that forks to background? Otherwise, the the JVM would just block, no?

Comment: Possibly related: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582745

Comment: Related to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/438313

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -u www-data
```

...will hang if it prompts for password. Have you've checked that the user the "startup script" runs as has sudoers permissions to do that?

Comment: and you can add ``-n`` to sudo so it exits with an error instead of waiting for password.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three possible issues:

- Your `expect fork` is wrong because your program doesn't actually fork. This is probably not the case since you are using a script but you might want to try `expect daemon` or not expect at all.
- Your java program doesn't actually go into daemon mode and thus requires to be put in the background. In other words you need a `&` at the end: `sudo -u www-data /path/to/grafserv-start.sh >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1`**`&`**
- Your Upstart is in a bad state. I don't know exactly how it happens but you can get upstart in a state where even if you edit the script to be correct it will still hang. If this happens rename the file (ie `/etc/init/[myservice]-1.conf` and try starting it till stops hanging. Once you get the script right rename the file to the correct name and restart the system.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed the exec in front of your script in upstart... I think it's necessary.  Try this:

`exec sudo -u www-data /path/to/grafserv-start.sh >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1`

Like Bittrance said, you might also want to make sure that your java program runs in the background.  Try appending a `&` or something to the end of the command in your script if you don't have any logic in your java program that runs it as a background process or a daemon.

Comment: Choices are "exec" or "script / end script". The example uses the latter.